# JNativeHook on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, debian-based

Am trying to use JNativeHook on the Raspberry Pi Platform

I have a simple java executable that works great on Mac and Windows, and I presumed should work fine on a Debian-based linux distribution....

However on-startup I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at Main.<init>(Main.java:159)
at Main$1.run(Main.java:129)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate the native library.
at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.loadNativeLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

So I have to do something extra for this to work on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile the native library contained in the jar to ARM.  It should compile without any issues on Linux, use `ant compile jar` to build.   If you want to [file a bug](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues?state=open) report I will work with you to get an arm binary supported.